# ClassCastException when passing a HashMap to a Java function

Tags: java, clojure, interop

I want to call a Java function (provided by SVNKit) with the following signature:

```
public abstract long getFile(String path,
                             long revision,
                             Map properties,
                             OutputStream contents)
                      throws SVNException
```

The parameters properties and contents are optional. In Clojure I call this function with:

```
(defn read-file
  ""
  [repository path]
  (let [properties (java.util.HashMap.)
        baos (java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.)]
    (.getFile repository path -1 properties baos)
    (.size baos)))
```

I get a ClassCastException on the properties parameter. When I leave it out (use nil instead of properties) it works fine. The ClassCastException doesn't give any information about what class it is expecting.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may be a stupid question - but are you sure the Map interface in the getFile method is a java.util.Map ?

Comment: Are you sure that's [the method signature](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/io/SVNRepository.html)?

Comment: "The ClassCastException doesn't give any information about what class it is expecting." This is terribly counter-productive. Instead of attempting to summarize an error message you say you don't understand, you should provide the actual error message and let others decide if it contains useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the SVNKit javadoc at http://svnkit.com/javadoc/index-all.html

there is not a method with the signature you listed. The closest seems to be:

```
public abstract long getFile(String path,
                             long revision,
                             SVNProperties properties,
                             OutputStream contents)
                      throws SVNException
```

from http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/io/SVNRepository.html

Comment: Thanks. Seems I have been looking at outdated examples and documentation all the time (http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/io/SVNRepository.html)